# Ramda.js pluck(key) type vs native map

Tags: typescript, types, ramda.js, pluck

Say I have the following code:

```
const results = //some complex datastructure generated by a third party api call
const reducedList = results.map((item) => item.awesome_key)
  .map((awesomeKeyList) => awesomeKeyList
    .reduce((memo, awesomeKey) => {//stuff},{})))
```

This code works like a charm. Now say I decided to use Ramda for the first map through pluck like so:

```
  import R from Ramda;
  R.pluck('awesome_key', results)
    .map((awesomeKeyList) => awesomeKeyList
      .reduce((memo, awesomeKey) => {},{})))
```

This will fail with:

```
Property 'reduce' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

The types on Ramda.pluck are:

```
pluck<T>(p: string|number, list: any[]): T[];
pluck(p: string|number): <T>(list: any[]) => T[];
```

What about those types prevents me from using reduce in this manner?

An example (simplified) structure:

```
things: [
  {
    awesome_key: [{
      long_name: 'string',
      short_name: 'string',
      types: {
        0: 'string from set',
        1?: 'string'
      }
    }]
    other_fields not relevant here
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you share some ([simplified](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) data that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Data from third party API added as requested

Comment: I get the same results with either format.  So there's probably something specific to your code or your data.

Comment: did you compare the result of `results.map((item) => item.awesome_key)` and `R.pluck('awesome_key', results)`?, it should be the same...

Answer (score 0):

Starting with this:

```
const results = [
  {
    awesome_key: [{
      long_name: 'foo',
      short_name: 'bar',
      types: {
        0: 'abc',
        1: 'def',
        2: 'ghi'
      }
    }, {
      long_name: 'baz',
      short_name: 'qux',
      types: {
        0: 'pqr',
        1: 'xyz'
      }
    }],
    other_fields: 'not relevant here'
    }
]
const interestingTypes = ['pqr', 'xyz'];
```

these two both have the same behavior, as far as I can tell:

```
results.map((item) => item.awesome_key)
  .map((addressComponentList) => addressComponentList.reduce((memo, addressComponent) => {
     if (interestingTypes.indexOf(addressComponent.types[0]) !== -1) {
       if (!memo[addressComponent.types[0]]) {
         memo[addressComponent.types[0]] = addressComponent.long_name
       }  
     }
     return memo
   },{}));

R.pluck('awesome_key', results)
  .map((addressComponentList) => addressComponentList.reduce((memo, addressComponent) => {
     if (interestingTypes.indexOf(addressComponent.types[0]) !== -1) {
       if (!memo[addressComponent.types[0]]) {
         memo[addressComponent.types[0]] = addressComponent.long_name
       }  
     }
     return memo
   },{}));
```

as does this, which is a little more idiomatic for Ramda:

```
R.pipe(
  R.pluck('awesome_key'),
  R.map(reduce((memo, addressComponent) => {
     if (interestingTypes.indexOf(addressComponent.types[0]) !== -1) {
       if (!memo[addressComponent.types[0]]) {
         memo[addressComponent.types[0]] = addressComponent.long_name
       }  
     }
     return memo
   },{}))
)(results)
```

Obviously this could probably be cleaned up a bit too, but I'm basing the code on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44131662).

`pluck('field', xs)` really should return the same sort of value as `xs.map(x => x.field)`.

The typescript signatures you list are not how I think of [`pluck`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pluck), which is documented as `:: k -> [{k: v}] -> [v]`, meaning that it accepts a (String) key and a list of Objects containing that key, returning a list of values